# Why can't tensorflow determine the shape of this expression?

Tags: tensorflow

I have the following expression which is giving me problems.  I have defined the batch_size as `batch_size = tf.shape(input_tensor)[0]` which dynamically determines the size of the batch based on the size of the input tensor to the model.  I have used it elsewhere in the code without issue.  What I am confused about is that when I run the following line of code it says the shape is (?, ?)  I would expect it to be (?, 128) because it knows the second dimension.

```
print(tf.zeros((batch_size, 128)).get_shape())
```

I want to know the shape since I am trying to do the following and I am getting an error.

```
    rnn_input = tf.reduce_sum(w * decoder_input, 1)
    last_out = decoder_outputs[t - 1] if t else tf.zeros((batch_size, 128))
    rnn_input = tf.concat(1, (rnn_input, last_out))
```

This code needs to set last_out to zero on the first time step.

Here is the error `ValueError: Linear expects shape[1] of arguments: [[None, None], [None, 1024]]`

I am doing something similar when I determine my initial state vector for the RNNs.

```
state = tf.zeros((batch_size, decoder_multi_rnn.state_size), tf.float32)
```

I also get (?, ?) when I try to print the size of state but it does not really throw any exceptions when I try to use it.

Comment: Are your print's inside a `with Session() as sess:` (or similar) expression? Have you tried doing something like `print(tf.zeros((batch_size.eval(), 128)).get_shape())`?

Comment: I am not inside a session.  I do not think I want to do that because then the model would be stuck with a fixed batch size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing static shapes and dynamic shapes. Static shape is what you get during `tensor.get_shape(tensor)` which is best-effort attempt to obtain shape, while dynamic shape comes from `sess.run(tf.shape(tensor))` and it is always defined.

To be more precise, `tf.shape(tensor)` creates an op in the graph that will produce shape tensor on `run` call. If you do `aop=tf.shape(tensor)[0]`, there's some magic through [_SliceHelper](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py#L250) that adds extra ops that will extract first element of the shape tensor on `run` call.

This means that `myval=tf.zeros((aop, 128))` has to run `aop` to obtain the dimensions and this means that first dimension of `myval` is undefined until you issue the `run` call. IE, your run call could look like `sess.run(myval, feed_dict={aop:2}`, where `feed_dict` overrides `aop` with 2. Hence static shape inference reports `?` for that dimension.

Comment: The real question is why does the static (inferred) shape **forgets** about the second dimension (128)? The resulting static shape is (?, ?) when it should be (?, 128)

Comment: I guess the question is what is stored `state_size`, I can't reproduce the `?` failure if I just put some integer there

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. I suspect it's a detail of how `_ConstantValue` is implemented in tensor_util.py [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d42facc3cc9611f0c9722c81551a7404a0bd3f6b/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py#L543). Shape inference calls that to figure out output of `tf.shape` during graph construction time, and it looks like it outputs `None` if there are any unknown entries

Comment: Shouldn't TensorFlow keep the information of the second dimension (128), which is not None?

Comment: Yes, that would be ideal

Answer (score 3):

*(EDIT: I rewrite an answer as what I wrote before was not up to the point)*

The quick fix to your issue is to use `set_shape()` to update the static (inferred) shape of the Tensor:

```py
input_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 32])
batch_size = tf.shape(input_tensor)[0]

res = tf.zeros((batch_size, 128))
print res.get_shape()  # prints (?, ?) WHEREAS one could expect (?, 128)

res.set_shape([None, 128])
print res.get_shape()  # prints (?, 128)
```

---

As for why TensorFlow looses the information about the second dimension being 128, I don't really know.

Maybe @Yaroslav will be able to answer.

EDIT:
The incorrect behavior was corrected following [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3102).

Comment: I suppose the problem is that I have defined my input tensor like. `input_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, TIME_STEPS, 128), 'input_tensor')`

Comment: The problem with that is I only want the first dimension to match.  The other dimensions will be different.